# Validar coluna de uma table

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma `table` que eu preencho ela via `ajax`, e funciona normal, porém ela está trazendo apenas uma linha, quando faço a verificação para saber se a linha está preenchido, ele me trás duas linhas.

```
 <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" id="tableNSerie" style="font-size:12px;">
  <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Código</th>
         <th>Produto</th>
         <th>Nº Série</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Essa é a `table`. E esses é o código que faço para verificar, preciso verificar a coluna Nº Série, tem apenas uma linha, porém quando aparece no console, aparece duas.

```
var trs = document.getElementById('tableNSerie');
var tr = trs.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var todos = null;
var td;
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if ($(td).text() === "") {
        todos++;
        console.log(todos);
    }
}
```

No caso o todos deveria retornar 1, pois há somente uma linha.

Essa é a forma como eu carrego a `table`

```
function CarregaProdutoNSerie() {
    var url = "/PedidoVenda/CarregaProdutoNControle";
    var id = $("#pedidoid").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { id: id }
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado !== null) {
                $("#tabelaNSerie").show();
                $("#tableNSerie tbody").html("");
                $.each(data.listaNSerie, function (i, item) {
                    $("#tableNSerie").append("<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + item.produto.codigo + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + item.produto.nome + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>");
                });                
            }
        }
    });}
```

Essa é a simulação [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hkjmdtyr/1/)

Comment: realmente, eu fiz duas alterações quando testei. Uma foi o pré-incremento e outra foi que na td do if eu escrevi um texto pra teste "zzz". ai funcionou. Mas parece funcionar com pré e  pós. veja: https://jsfiddle.net/7jf5sqgb/

Comment: @cpll vc salvou as alterações? Pois ainda está do mesmo jeito.

Comment: editei o link https://jsfiddle.net/7jf5sqgb/

Comment: @cpll ai aparece só um, mas quando comparo com valor vazio, ele me trás dois, que estranho.

Comment: sim, por isso me enganei na resposta

Comment: coloca um id nessa td

Comment: Em vez de null, inicie a declaração com zero antes de iterar: `var todos = 0;`e no for declare seu iterator: `for (var i=0; i < tr.length; i++)`, pegue apenas o `<tr>` da `<tbody>`, e não do `<thread>`: e depois veja o que acontece.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a variável `tr` pega todos os `tr` em `#tableNSerie`, inclusive o `tr` do cabeçalho, que está em `thead`. Isso deve funcionar:

```
var tr = trs.querySelector("tbody").getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que primeiro você deve fazer o `append` no local correto, que é dentro das tags `<tbody></tbody>`:

```
$("#tableNSerie tbody").append("<tr>" ...);
```

Se você remover a primeira `<tr>` que também é contabilizada, por estar dentro da sua `<thead>`, ele irá considerar a partir do seu `<tbody>`:

```
 //você pode aplicar `var` na primeira declaração e as demais juntar por uma vírgula:
   var todos=0,
       table = document.getElementById('tableNSerie'),
       tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
       tr.splice(0, 1); //remove a primeira tr que está em <thread> do array

   //é recomendado declarar sempre a variável quando ela é iniciada:
   for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        //não é necessário usar jquery para pegar texto
        if ( td.textContent === "") {
            todos++;
            console.log(todos);
        }
    }
```